# Printing to multiple files with shell script for loop variable

Tags: bash, for-loop

None of the files are showing up, I tried putting the file to be written to in quotes but just no files are being written all I am getting is one file called person.txt

```
   #!/bin/sh
    cut -f 1 $1 > temp1.txt
    cut -f 2-3 $2 > temp2.txt
    for ((i=3;i<103;i++)); do
            cut -f $i $1 > temp3.txt
            paste temp1.txt temp2.txt temp3.txt > $HOME/Desktop/Plots/person$iPlot.txt
    done
```

Comment: We need comments showing what is this code meant to do. At  present it's difficult to distinguish the code's mistakes from its peculiarities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having tested it, a problem in your script is

```
 $HOME/Desktop/Plots/person$iPlot.txt
```

Bash is not going to substitute your variable `i` as you are expecting, but tries to resolve a variable `iPlot` instead. As this variable has not been assigned any value, you'll end up with `person.txt`. This happens as bash tries to resolve variables as entire words separated e.g. by space or period.

To make sure that your variable `i` is used, try

```
$HOME/Desktop/Plots/person${i}Plot.txt
```

instead.

Comment: Thank-you!! Do you have any idea why it takes like a minutes to run? Each column has about 20000 lines but I feel like these are still simple enough commands for that but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You're doing a lot of file I/O. It would be faster to read the file named by `$1` into memory once, then iterate over the columns, instead of re-reading the file every time just to get one column.

Comment: @B.Monster See chepner's comment.